# How can I find a implementation of a data-structure corresponding to a mathematical Set in R?

Tags: r, data-structures, set

I am new to R and I would like to know where I can find a standard implementation of a data-structure corresponding to a mathematical Set in R. Something similar to pythons built-in Type set for example.

Comment: A little more detail (for those of us not knowing about Python's `set` type)?  R does have set operators that can operate on vectors -- see `?union`

Comment: This is a good question.  It turns out that lists in R do not have accurate set manipulation tools - `intersect`, for instance, does not behave properly.  See [the vignette](+1 Just because [the vignette](http://ftp.heanet.ie/mirrors/cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sets/vignettes/sets.pdf) to the `sets` package suggested by Spacedman.

Comment: @Iterator: The four set operations on the "sets" help page are not documented to accept lists as arguments. Offering a list is the "improper behavior". If you want something more mathematical, then install the sets package:http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sets/index.html , which does implement a set datatype.

Comment: @DWin: That's my point. :) I have used lists, post-`unique` to do set operations via commands like `setdiff()` in the `base` package.  Now, my stomach turns because of the issues raised in the vignette.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you need to learn how to search CRAN, the R archive. I found this:

http://ftp.heanet.ie/mirrors/cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sets/index.html

Note the URL there is my local mirror. Start at www.r-project.org and carry on.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Especially for the tip about CRAN.

Comment: +1 Simply because [the vignette](http://ftp.heanet.ie/mirrors/cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sets/vignettes/sets.pdf) is well worth a read for anyone using lists to mimic sets in R.  Very interesting stuff.